# If $f:M\to N$ is a morphism of $A$-modules, counter-example to $M\cong \operatorname{ker}f\oplus \operatorname{im}f$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

If $f:V\to W$ is a linear transformation between (not necessarily finite-dimensional) vector spaces, then
$$V\cong \operatorname{ker}f\oplus \operatorname{im}f.$$
(This is the external direct sum, as usual in modern algebra.)

I absolutely don't expect a similar result to be true for $A$-modules. (We have conditions under which this holds, given by the splitting lemma.) But I couldn't find a counterexample.

So, what is a morphism of $A$-modules $f:M\to N$ such that $M$ is **not** isomorphic to $\operatorname{ker}f\oplus \operatorname{im}f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the $\Bbb{Z}$-modules $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$. Then $\phi:\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ defined by $\phi(a)=a\mod 2$ is a $\Bbb{Z}$ module homomorphism but the direct sum of the kernel and image is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest counter-example I can think of is
$$0\to 2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0.$$
$\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, as $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have torsion.